# PHP artisan key:generate does not update .env file (laravel 5.2 on AWS EC2 Ubuntu)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I renamed my `example.env` to `.env` in order to remove previous errors with my application. However, I noticed

`APP_KEY=SomeRandomString`

near the top of the `.env` file an new something was off. When I run

`PHP artisan key:generate` and recheck the `.env` file...nothing happens.

My stack includes Apache2, Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), PHP 5.5.36

Comment: Do you have the command result? Can it be that `PHP` is not the same as `php` and `PHP` is not found? Also check `/storage/logs/laravel.log` to see if that throws any error.

Comment: Run `php artisan optimize` then regenerate your key.

Comment: Also check the permissions, can apache write the .env file?

Comment: @milz `PHP` over `php` throws an error

Comment: @AguV file permissions for `.env` is 646 so that should allow it...right?

Comment: @Rifki your answer was correct! can you list it separately and I will mark it?

Comment: @MarkusProctor done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Laravel still uses the older `.env` file even it has been deleted, try to optimize the class loader using `php artisan optimize` then regenerate your key.